# How to point two domains to one ip address with a sub-domain

Tags: htaccess, redirects, dns

I am a little stuck here I currently have a domain:

`www.exammple.org` & `m.example.org`

I want to point `m.mainsite.example` to `m.example.org`

I already have an A record created for `m.mainsite.example`, I need to know what I have to do to the server where `example.org` is on.

I have this site on an Unix Apache server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you probably want is called a `CNAME` Record. This is like a softlink to a domain.

You would add it wherever your DNS provider has the `A` record you mention, and it would look something like

```
m.mainsite.example. CNAME m.example.org.
```

This tells the DNS resolver that whenever it sees `m.mainsite.example`, it should go try and resolve `m.example.org`

Note the trailing dots -- some DNS providers require them, some do not. When in doubt, use them.

Note that this doubles the initial lookup time for someone visiting your site; they have to do two lookups now.

A faster way that requires more maintenance is to just add an `A` record for `m.mainsite.example` that points to the IP address at `example.org`. If you do that, you will need to update both in case of a new IP address, or a failover scenario.

Comment: Thanks Peter... we having a small problem with having this properly redirect when using a mobile browser. I have added user agent conditionals to the .htaccess file but still nothing. Would or could you recommend a solution. We are using jQuery mobile on a linux box.

Comment: I would definitely recommend the DNS CNAME route. I can't comment on your htaccess file without seeing it, unfortunately!